# SQL Server 2017. Applying latest CU (26) before installation doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql-server, docker, installation, patch

Here what I tried (if it makes a difference in a docker build) but...

```
cd Install
.\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.exe /x:SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU /u
.\SQLServer2017-KB5005226-x64.exe /x:SQLServer2017_CU /u
C:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU\SETUP.exe /q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /ACTION=PrepareImage /UpdateEnabled=True /UpdateSource=c:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017_CU /INSTANCEID=MSSQlSERVER /FEATURES=SQLEngine

Microsoft .NET Framework CasPol 4.8.3761.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.3761.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

WARNING: The .NET Framework does not apply CAS policy by default. Any settings
shown or modified by CasPol will only affect applications that opt into using
CAS policy.

Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131738 for more information.


Success
Microsoft .NET Framework CasPol 4.8.3761.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.3761.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

WARNING: The .NET Framework does not apply CAS policy by default. Any settings
shown or modified by CasPol will only affect applications that opt into using
CAS policy.

Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131738 for more information.


Success

C:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU\SETUP.exe /Q /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="oracle#1" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /UPDATEENABLED=false

SQL Server 2017 transmits information about your installation experience, as well as other usage and performance data, to Microsoft to help improve the product. To learn more about SQL Server 2017 data processing and privacy controls, please see the Privacy Statement.
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2017 14.00.1000.169
Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft.  All rights reserved.

Success
```

As you can see no errors were reported by the PrepareImage stage, and the Installation appears to have worked. Except for the fact that I get this..

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>sqlcmd -Usa -Poracle#1
1> select @@version
2> go

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)
        Aug 22 2017 17:04:49
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)


(1 rows affected)
1> quit
```

Which I believe means I am running an unpatched version of the RTM software.

Did I do something wrong..

Here's my Dockerfile if anyone is feeling really adventurous

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
#
ADD https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/releases/download/v1.1/LogMonitor.exe LogMonitor.exe 
#
# Download and install Visual C++ Redistributable
#
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe .
RUN powershell -command Start-Process c:\vc_redist.x64.exe  -Wait -ArgumentList "/q"
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x64.exe
#
# Download and Install .NET Framework 4.8
#
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2d6bb6b2-226a-4baa-bdec-798822606ff1/8494001c276a4b96804cde7829c04d7f/ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe .
RUN powershell -command c:\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /q  /norestart
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item c:\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe
#
RUN powershell -command New-Item -ItemType "directory" C:\INSTALL  
#
# Unpack SQL Server
#
WORKDIR c:/INSTALL
COPY SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.exe .
COPY SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.box .
RUN powershell -command .\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.exe /x:SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU /u
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.exe
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU.box
#
# Unpack Cummulative update #26: SQLServer2017-KB5005226-x64
#
# ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/4/F/C4F908C9-98ED-4E5F-88D5-7D6A5004AEBD/SQLServer2017-KB5005226-x64.exe  c:/SQLServer2017_CU.exe
COPY  SQLServer2017-KB5005226-x64.exe SQLServer2017_CU.exe 
RUN powershell -command .\SQLServer2017_CU.exe /x:SQLServer2017_CU /u
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item SQLServer2017_CU.exe
#
# Apply Cummlative Update for SQL Server to the Installation Directory
#
RUN C:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU\SETUP.exe /q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /ACTION=PrepareImage /UpdateEnabled=True /UpdateSource=c:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017_CU /INSTANCEID=MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQLEngine
#
# Install SQL Server
#
RUN C:\INSTALL\SQLServer2017-DEV-x64-ENU\SETUP.exe /Q /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="oracle#1" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /UPDATEENABLED=false 
#
WORKDIR c:/
COPY prepareMounts.ps1 .docker 
RUN powershell -command Set-Service  -Name "MSSQLSERVER" -StartupType "Manual"
RUN powershell -command Stop-Service -Name "MSSQLSERVER"
RUN powershell -command c:\prepareMounts.ps1
RUN powershell -command Remove-Item c:\prepareMounts.ps1
#
SHELL [ "powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
COPY Start.ps1 .
#ENTRYPOINT [ "powershell","c:\\Start.ps1","-ACCEPT_EULA $ENV:ACCEPT_EULA","-SA_PASSWORD $ENV:SA_PASSWORD"]
ENTRYPOINT powershell "c:\\Start.ps1 -ACCEPT_EULA $ENV:ACCEPT_EULA -SA_PASSWORD $ENV:SA_PASSWORD
#ENTRYPOINT ["powershell","wait-event"]
```

Comment: (1) in one script I see /UPDATEENABLED=True and in the other I see /UPDATEENABLED=False. (2) when you run `sqlcmd` are you doing that inside the container or on the host? If you are on the host I suspect you are connecting to the default instance _on your machine_, not the one inside the container. That said, I haven't had to manually install SQL Server (slipstreamed or not) inside a container, why don't you just do `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`? That should get you a container ready to run - no installing SQL Server, no applying CUs...

Comment: (Granted, I am using linux containers, if you are trying to use Windows containers you are in relatively uncharted territory.)

Comment: Aaron: I already use the Linux based MSSQL containers for the majority of my qa process. There are two possible reasons for getting windows containers working (1) I wanted to get Windows based containers working for a 'special run' scenario so I could ensure that I don't have any "gothca's" realted to '/' Vs '\' etc if some runs the software I am developing against a Windows database or (2) I'm a masochist :)

Comment: I actually got this working with 2019 my modifying my docker container as shown...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working with 2019 and CU13 using the following docker file

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
#
ADD https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/releases/download/v1.1/LogMonitor.exe LogMonitor.exe 
#
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
#
# Download and install Visual C++ Redistributable
#
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe .
RUN Start-Process c:\vc_redist.x64.exe  -Wait -ArgumentList "/q"
RUN Remove-Item c:\vc_redist.x64.exe
#
# Download and Install .NET Framework 4.8
#
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2d6bb6b2-226a-4baa-bdec-798822606ff1/8494001c276a4b96804cde7829c04d7f/ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe .
RUN c:\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /q  /norestart
RUN Remove-Item c:\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe
#
RUN New-Item -ItemType "directory" C:\INSTALL  
#
# Unpack SQL Server
#
WORKDIR c:/INSTALL
COPY SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.exe .
COPY SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.box .
RUN .\SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.exe /x:SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU /u
RUN Remove-Item SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.exe
RUN Remove-Item SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.box
#
# Unpload the Cummulative update #13: SQLServer2019-KB5005679-x64
#
RUN New-Item -ItemType "directory" CU
# ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/e/7/6e72dddf-dfa4-4889-bc3d-e5d3a0fd11ce/SQLServer2019-KB5005679-x64.exe  CU\SQLServer2019-KB5005679-x64
COPY SQLServer2019-KB5005679-x64.exe CU
#
# Install SQL Server Applying the Cummlative Update
#
RUN C:\INSTALL\SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU\SETUP.exe /Q /ACTION=Install /UPDATEENABLED=TRUE /UpdateSource="C:\INSTALL\CU" /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT='NT AUTHORITY\System' /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS='BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS' /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="oracle#1" 
#
WORKDIR c:/
COPY prepareMounts.ps1 .
RUN Set-Service  -Name "MSSQLSERVER" -StartupType "Manual"; `
    Stop-Service -Name "MSSQLSERVER"; `
    c:\prepareMounts.ps1; `
    Remove-Item c:\prepareMounts.ps1
#
COPY Start.ps1 .
#ENTRYPOINT [ "powershell","c:\\Start.ps1","-ACCEPT_EULA $ENV:ACCEPT_EULA","-SA_PASSWORD $ENV:SA_PASSWORD"]
ENTRYPOINT powershell "c:\\Start.ps1 -ACCEPT_EULA $ENV:ACCEPT_EULA -SA_PASSWORD $ENV:SA_PASSWORD
#ENTRYPOINT ["powershell","wait-event"]
```

It appears my mistake was to try to unpack the CU before slipstreaming it in as part of the install.

Unfortunately with servercore:ltsc:2019, SQL Server 2017 and CU26 I then end up in code page hell. Servercore:ltsc2019 is locked to codepage 65001 (Apparently this cannot be altered as it's inherited from the underlying VM). This means that the install fails with

```
Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
10/15/2021 3:14:39 PM          912 Error            Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgr...
```

Comment: Now trying servercore:ltsc:2016...

Comment: Crash and Burn: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591825/cannot-install-sql-server-2017-with-slipstreamed-cu26-into-windows-container-bas